# Php, socket and connecting to pop3-server

Tags: php, pop3

I'm trying to connect to the pop3-server with php. Here is my code:

```
$pop3Server = 'mail.roller.ru';
$pop_conn = fsockopen($pop3Server, 110, $errno, $errstr, 10);
print fgets($pop_conn, 1024);


Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in /home/ockonal/public_html/mail_parser.php on line 45

Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to mail.roller.ru:110 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution) in /home/ockonal/public_html/mail_parser.php on line 45

Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/ockonal/public_html/mail_parser.php on line 46
```

What's wrong? I'm sure in pop3-server address. It doesn't print anything.

Comment: "Temporary failure in name resolution" means it'll somehow work some time later. Did you wait and try again? (The fgets error is because `fsockopen` returned `false` instead of a valid socket.)

Comment: Don't forget about http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php, which can also open connections to POP3 servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Temporary failure in name resolution

Isn't it clear enough?

if your server having troubles with name resolving, you can use `62.113.86.215` IP address instead.