# PHP, login to pop3-server

Tags: php, pop3

I have another one problem with pop3. Here is connection to pop3-server:

```
$pop3Server = '62.113.86.215';  // mail.roller.ru
$pop3User = 'mail-robot%roller.ru';

$pop_conn = fsockopen($pop3Server, 110, $errno, $errstr, 30);
echo fgets($pop_conn, 1024);
```

It returns OK. The next step is login:

```
fputs($pop_conn, 'USER '.$pop3User.'\r\n');
//stream_set_timeout($pop_conn, 3);
print fgets($pop_conn, 1024);
```

And I get time-out. Why?

p.s. Here is full code: http://pastie.org/934170

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708739/php-socket-and-connecting-to-pop3-server What about sticking to one question?

Comment: @zneak, but it's different questions. And I marked that question as solved.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'\r\n' should be "\r\n". http://php.net/types.string

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries to do that kind of stuff. Take a look, for example, at here: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebpop